# How to In App Purchases with ReactJS and Capacitor

Tags: reactjs, in-app-purchase, capacitor

I am using Capacitor to generate both the IOS and Android apps (not using Iconic) - this works well, but we are trying to implement IAP (for IOS only at this stage) and cannot figure it out.

I have followed various guides (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase-2 and https://purchase.cordova.fovea.cc/ and https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/in-app-purchases) but simply cannot get it working with React (not React Native)

Can someone point me in the right direction, or provide sample code?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't describe what is going wrong, but here's a basic configuration that works for me on iOS.

I'm only including the part about the store:

**index.tsx**

```
import { IAPProduct, InAppPurchase2 } from '@ionic-native/in-app-purchase-2';

const startStoreEventListeners = () => {
  if (isPlatformMobile()) {
    document.addEventListener(
      'deviceready',
      () => {    
        const store = InAppPurchase2;
        // Needed to use IAP + cordova plugins.

        // Set debug messages.
        // Default.
        store.verbosity = store.QUIET;
        // store.verbosity = store.DEBUG;

        store.register([
          {
            id: subMonthly,
            type: store.PAID_SUBSCRIPTION,
          },
          {
            id: subAnnual,
            type: store.PAID_SUBSCRIPTION,
          },
        ]);
    
        // Upon approval, verify the receipt.
        store.when(subMonthly).approved((product: IAPProduct) => {
          product.verify();
        });
        store.when(subAnnual).approved((product: IAPProduct) => {
          product.verify();
        });

        // Upon receipt validation, mark the subscription as owned.
        store.when(subMonthly).verified((product: IAPProduct) => {
          product.finish();
        });
        store.when(subAnnual).verified((product: IAPProduct) => {
          product.finish();
        });
    
        // Track all store errors
        store.error((err: Error) => {
          debugLog('Store Error', JSON.stringify(err));
        });
    
        // https://billing-dashboard.fovea.cc/setup/cordova
        store.validator =
          'https://validator.fovea.cc/v1/validate?appName=secret';
        store.refresh();

        startIonic();
      },
      false,
    );
  } else {
    startIonic();
  }
};

startStoreEventListeners();

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Note that [@ionic-native packages are deprecated and need to be converted](https://ionicframework.com/blog/a-new-chapter-for-ionic-native/).